# An example of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I want to know an example of a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that

$n \Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_{kn}| \to 0 \ (n \to \infty)$ and

$n^2 \Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_{kn}| \to \infty \ (n \to \infty)$.

Comment: Have you considered sequences that use natural log?

Comment: Would you like fries with your order?  Stick to questions, please. Don't treat this site like a drive-through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest example I can think of is $a_n = \dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}}$. This gives us:

$$n\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}|a_{kn}| = n\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(kn)^{3/2}} = \dfrac{1}{n^{1/2}}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k^{3/2}} = \dfrac{\zeta(3/2)}{n^{1/2}} \to 0 \ \text{as} \ n \to \infty,$$

$$n^2\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}|a_{kn}| = n^2\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(kn)^{3/2}} = n^{1/2}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k^{3/2}} = \zeta(3/2)n^{1/2} \to +\infty \ \text{as} \ n \to \infty.$$